# CakePHP integer input maxlength is always 3

Tags: cakephp, integer, field, cakephp-2.0, maxlength

Doesn't matter what I try, CakePHP 2.4.9 with a simple integer field and it forces maxlength to 3.

Code: `echo $this->Form->input('year', array('maxlength'=>'4'));`
still doesn't change the 'maxlength' field on the number input type

Tried adding validation in the model with the maxlength rule, still no go!
Integer size in MySQL is 11!

Comment: I have tried with CakePHP 2.4.9 , anh it is normally .
Do you check any errors appeared ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the type to text:

`echo $this->Form->input('year', array('maxlength'=>'4', 'type' => 'text'));`

For CakePHP changing it to a specific number that's weird though.